# How do you encourage others to respond?

Tags: meaning, questions

How do you encourage others to respond? What's the most common way to invite others to respond?

Let me give you some examples. Which of the following ways is more commonplace than others?

> You know what (...) means, from what I can gather. __________?
>
> 1. Does anyone want to tell us?
> 2. Who wants to say the answer?
> 3. Who knows the answer?
> 4. What is the answer to the question?

If there are more effective ways, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd say not "say the answer" but "give the answer". Also, you might want to use more of "would" to make the questions sound more polite:

- Is there anyone who's like to give the answer?
- Would anyone like to share their thoughts with us?

Of course, a lot depends on the situation. There is nothing wrong with your questions above.

Come to think of it, there is one thing which I find a bit weird. You assume that they know the meaning. So, why are you saying "who knows the answer?" if you have just said that you know they all know it?